# How to use Oracle 10g REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract a string using a string delimiter

Tags: regex, string, oracle

I have many strings that I need to tokenise - an example is shown below.

```
NAME:ALAN GREYINTACC:999ACCOUNT:12345678SORT:654321REF:ABC 7654321
```

I can use a combination of `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` to do this, but I was hoping that there might be an easier way to perform this using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

I've looked at anchors, but could only find references to start string `^` and end string `$`.

Is there such a thing as an 'in string' anchor? e.g. If I wanted the account number from this string, I want everything after `ACCOUNT:` and before `SORT:`

Any replies appreciated,

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE` instead for this purpose. This can help you to capture groups(like `\1`) from the matching and use it in replacement. See below example:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE('NAME:ALAN GREYINTACC:999ACCOUNT:12345678SORT:654321REF:ABC 7654321',
                  '.*ACCOUNT:(.+?)SORT.*',
                  '\1') "SOME_VALUE"
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I'd just worked this out by trying to solve the question. REGEXP_SUBSTR does not allow for capturing of matches, so REGEXP_REPLACE is the way to go. +1.

Answer (score 0):

There's no 'in string' anchor per say: there are patterns that your regex can match. Even 'anchor' are really matches for the end and beginning of the line.

This regex, for example, will match `ACCOUNT:` followed by anything, followed by `SORT:` and store this 'anything' in the first capturing group (indicated in the regex with the parenthesis)

```
ACCOUNT:(.*?)SORT:
```

- `.` is any character (except newline)
- `*` is a quantifier, means 0 or more times
- `?` makes the quantifier lazy (will stop at the shortest match, useful if your data is `ACCOUNT:123SORT:456SORT:789` and you only want to select `123`, not `123SORT:456`)

Comment: Thanks Robin. Unfortunately, due to the state of the data I'm being supplied with, there can be pretty much anything between ACCOUNT: and SORT: so I can't just look for numbers.

Comment: @user3463817: I see. I updated my answer accordingly, but I'm not familiar with oracle's regex and I don't know how to display the captured value. Good luck

Comment: Having played around with REGEXP_SUBSTR, I couldn't figure a way of actually using the capture. As Sabuj suggests, REGEXP_REPLACE is required for this.

Comment: Thank you all very much for answering this question. Much appreciated! REGEXP_REPLACE it is!!!!